# Is there a foundational approach that takes "structure" as primitive?

Tags: lo.logic, foundations, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, elementary-theory-category-of-sets

As per the title, I'd be curious to know if there have been attempts at constructing a foundation of mathematics taking, somehow, purely the notion of "structure" as primitive, maybe via a system of axioms that formalizes how structure can be transported, restricted, extended, encoded, etc.
I'm being intentionally vague about all the above.

I am aware of the existence of structural *set theories*, such as ETCS which formalizes the notion of the category of sets in the language of category theory, but I'm unsure whether to consider this really a theory "about structure" rather than just about *sets* seen from an intrinsic non-materialistic viewpoint. Maybe somebody has some arguments in favor of actually seeing it as a "theory of structure".

Same doubts about (homotopy or not) type theories.

Comment: Can you expand on how type theory fails to meet your desiderata? I'd argue that taking "structure" as primitive is precisely what type theory does. For instance, in type theory, the natural numbers $\mathbb N$ are defined via a universal property.

Comment: @TimCampion I'd expect such a foundation to use a word at least similar to "structure" (as an internal primitive) and to use it in such a way that it reflects our intuition of structures. Are you suggesting type theory satisfies this if we read the word "type" as "structure"? If I read $\mathbb{N} : \text{Set}$  as "the naturals have the structure of a set" there seems to be something missing. How would I talk about "the whole structure of $\mathbb{N}$" inside type theory? (This reminds me that Ocaml uses the keyword struct.)

Comment: I expanded on the "types as structure" point of view, and how I view it as related to "structural set theories" (perhaps a misnomer from this perspective), at https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/01/from_set_theory_to_type_theory.html .  Obviously the word "type" cannot be grammatically simply substituted for "structure", but it has roughly the same meaning.

Comment: @MikeShulman Actually... I can't think of an example where I couldn't simply use the word "structure" in place of "type"... Maybe I'd also use "point" instead of "term" if I were doing this... But I'm always a bit confused about what this "pre-theoretical notion of 'structure'"  is supposed to be, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold I don't know where "$\mathbb N: Set$" i coming from. In my understanding of type theory, one would typically have $\mathbb N: Type$, which I think could easily be read as $\mathbb N: \text{Structure}$ -- "the naturals are a point of the structure of structures", i.e. a structure. I'd concede, though, that structuralism is not really among the philosophical perspectives traditionally emphasized by type theorists -- it's not traditionally presented as a theory of structures, so it's surprising (but true, I think) to realize that it could perfectly well be presented this way.

Comment: You may also be interested by Steve Awodey's "Structuralism, Invariance, and Univalence" article, at http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/preprints/siu.pdf